# Unknown authentication strategy "local" passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I keep getting the `Error: Unknown authentication strategy "local"` error.
This is a bit of my main file (server.js):

```js
...
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

...

// Initialize passport
const initializePassport = require("./passport-config");
initializePassport(
    passport,
    (email) => searchUser({ email: email }),
    (id) => searchUser({ id: id })
);

...

// Post request - Login user
app.post(
    "/login",
    checkNotAuthenticated,
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login",
        failureFlash: true,
    })
);
```

this is my passport config file (passport-config.js):

```js
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "No user with that email" });
        }

        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
            if (e) {
                return done(e);
            }
            if (result) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Password incorrect" });
            }
        });

        passport.use(
            new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, authenticateUser)
        );
        passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id));
        passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
            return done(null, getUserById(id));
        });
    };
}

module.exports = initialize;
```

i can't figure out whats the issue here, i'm also pretty new to passport, node and express
this is not my code but i took it from a [tutorial in a yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RCnNyD0L-s&t=1s) that didn't (somehow) work, so i tried making it work, i also was trying to add mongodb storage but i dont think thats the issue

Comment: You have put the three passport lines inside the authenticateUser function but they are only supposed to run once, in the initialize function. Compare to [source](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Nodejs-Passport-Login/blob/master/passport-config.js)

Comment: @ChrisG i don't get what you're trying to say

Comment: Take the `};` close to the end of the config file and move it up, after the bcrypt.compare block.

Comment: @ChrisG now i get `Error: data and hash arguments required`, i console logged `user` and it returns a `Promise { <pending> }`, how do i wait until the promise is "solved"?

Comment: Your code has more issues. This also illustrates why imo, learning from youtube videos is bad. You don't really learn anything, you just blindly follow along, and the slightest mistake gets you stuck because you lack the basics. You don't understand what errors mean, you can't debug, etc. - I don't mean to be rude, I'm just explaining why I'm not going to debug your code any further. Because it's pointless. Look at the source files; those work. Look at how they are different from your code.

Comment: ur 100% right, sorry if i was rude, thanks for the lesson